# Shorten width of input box in Bootstrap form column without effecting other elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

The two circle input boxes I would like to decrease the size of it but keep everything else intact.  It has a class of `hasTimepicker` to do something like this but with flex CSS, which I am not super familiar with, havent been able to figure it out. How would I do this?  I would like to use `rem` like Bootstrap but not sure if that is necessary or not.

```
   <div class="form-row">
.
.
.
    <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="input-group mr-2">
                <!-- ko if: position() == 'Between' -->
                <input autocomplete="off" data-bind="time: { options : { defaultTime:'8:00', showPeriod: true, showLeadingZero: false} }" maxlength="8" name="StartTime" placeholder="11:00 AM" type="text" value="" id="tp1586096023489" class="hasTimepicker w-25"> 
                <div class="input-group-prepend input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">-</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: position() != 'On' -->
                <input autocomplete="off" data-bind="time: { options : { defaultTime:'8:00', showPeriod: true, showLeadingZero: false} }" maxlength="8" name="EndTime" placeholder="4:00 PM" type="text" value="" id="tp1586096023490" class="hasTimepicker active"> 
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if : position() != 'On' -->
                <div class="input-group-prepend input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">on</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
    <select id="DateString" name="DateString"><option value=""> - All Days -</option>
    <option>Fri. Feb 28, 2020</option>
    <option>Sat. Feb 29, 2020</option>
    </select>        </div>
        </div>
.
.
.
     </div>
```

[image: Sho]

Comment: try adding margin-left:auto to DateString?

Comment: Didnt work, sorry

Comment: Without changing the html `transform-origin:left;transform:scaleX(.7)` but it's janky, You'll need to wrap the inputs in an element and lower their width.